# ReactJS - fixed header and footer, scroll middle area only

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a chatbot using React/Typescript. For that, the header should remain fixed at the top and footer should remain fixed at the bottom. Only the text / chat feed area should be scrollable and fill the rest of the screen.

A snip shown below. I'm not able to achieve this using `flex flex-col justify-between` without hardcoding the height of the chat feed (I am using Tailwind CSS, **but would appreciate any CSS info provided**)

My render method returns the below - note the hardcoded height in the chatfeed `h-[800px]`

```
(
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between">
      <main className="items-center justify-center h-[800px] overflow-y-auto">
        <ChatFeed />
      </main>
      <footer className="min-w-min bg-slate-200 p-5 sticky  shadow-2xl">
        <ChatTextBox />
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
```

How can I achieve the below, without hardcoding the height, which ofcourse won't work in all screens?

[image]

Comment: Make the body "container" `margin-bottom` the exact same size as the footer, and `margin-top` the same size as the header.  You can then set the `vh` as 100%  and your overflow to `scroll` and it should work as expected.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by setting the height of overall `div` to a calculated value `h-[calc(100vh-64px)]`

```
<div className="flex flex-col justify-between h-[calc(100vh-64px)]">
```

where 64px is the height of the fixed header